# Does 'BitSet' store bits or integers?

Tags: scala, bit-manipulation, bitset

I am confused about `BitSet`. Does a `BitSet` data structure stores 1s and 0s?

```
val b = BitSet(0, 2, 3)
```

means store 1s for bit locations 0, 2 and 3?

If so, what are the max. no. of bits, 32 or 64?

Answer (score 8):

A `BitSet` in Scala is implemented as an `Array[Long]`, where each bit signals the presence of a number in the array. `Long` is 64 bit in Scala (on the JVM). One such `Long` can store values 0 to 63, the next one after it 64 to 127, on so on. This is possible since we're only talking about positive numbers and don't need to account for the sign.

Given your example:

```
BitSet(0, 2, 3)
```

We can store all these numbers inside a single `Long`, which in binary would be:

```
1101
```

Since we're in the range of 0 to 63, this works on a single `Long` value.

In general, the upper limit, or the biggest value stored inside a `BitSet` in Scala is `Int.MaxValue`, meaning `2^31-1` (2147483647). In order to store it, you'd need `2147483647 / 64` "bits" representing the number, which is ~= 33554432 longs. This is why storing large numbers in a bit set can get quite expensive, and it is usually only recommended when you're dealing with numbers in around the hundreds.

As a side note, `immutable.BitSet` has a special implementation in Scala (of the `BitSetLike` trait), namely `BitSet1` and `BitSet2`, which are backed by a one and two longs, respectively, avoiding the need to allocate an additional array to wrap them.

Comment: So in order to store 3 number `0 2, 3`, BitSet uses only 1 Long which is `1101` A.K.A `13`? And in order to store 1 number `2^31-1`(2147483647), BitSet uses `2147483647 / 64=33,554,432` Longs?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/BitSet.html):

> Bitsets are sets of non-negative integers which are represented as
>   variable-size arrays of bits packed into 64-bit words. The memory
>   footprint of a bitset is determined by the largest number stored in
>   it.

Given that the API deals with adding and removing `Int`s, then it seems reasonable to believe the maximum bit that can be set is a max integer, i.e. `2^31-1`.  Looking at [the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/BitSet.scala#L43) for `scala.collection.immutable.BitSet`, there's also an assert to disallow negative integers (which makes sense according to the above description):

```
def + (elem: Int): BitSet = {
    require(elem >= 0, "bitset element must be >= 0")
```